# How to remove semi-duplicates in Mongo DB aggregation?

Tags: mongodb

Consider the following collection:

```
[
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "flagField": false,
        "extraField": "1"
    },
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "flagField": true,
        "extraField": "2"
    },
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "flagField": true,
        "extraField": "3"
    },
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "flagField": false,
        "extraField": "4"
    },
    {
        "userId": 2,
        "flagField": true,
        "extraField": "1"
    }
]
```

How would one remove semi-duplicates for users based on the `"flagField": true` criteria and get the following result?

```
[
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "flagField": true,
        "extraField": "2"
    },
    {
        "userId": 2,
        "flagField": true,
        "extraField": "1"
    }
]
```

Seems that `$group` stage doesn't provide an accumulator that allows you to pick one full document out of several semi-duplicates based on a condition (`flagField:true` in this case).

In case there will be several matching documents with `"flagField": true` for a given user it's OK to pick any but once again it should be a full original document and not a composition of several semi-duplicates. I.e. all the extra fields should come from the same original document.

Comment: I don't know if I get what you want but if I've understood correctly you can try something like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/27CoqKS0im4). I can explain better if it solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed solves the problem I have formulated in the question.

Comment: More flexible: https://mongoplayground.net/p/22cvUZMtl2n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this aggregation query:

- First `$match` to filter documents that match the flag.
- Then `$group` by `userId`. That means will not be duplicated users. Using `$ROOT` the entire object (i.e. a user) is added into `data` object so it fits the part "it should be a full original document and not a composition of several semi-duplicates". And using `$first` it gets one value if exists more than one `userId`.
- And last stage is `$project` to output desired format. As pointed by [user20042973](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20042973/user20042973) you can easily use `$replaceWith` to set the value from `data`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "flagField": yourFlag
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$userId",
      "data": {
        "$first": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": "$data"
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GqV2sADxI84)